# DIV overlap with browser resize

Tags: html, css, wordpress, overlap

I know this has been posted before, but I am inclined to think that the issue with my website (***) is different.

The website looks exactly like I want it to when it is at full size, but when I go to make the browser size smaller, the text ("ABOUT INTERNATIONAL PARK OF COMMERCE.." and below) all overlap the sub navigation (dark grey) to the left of it.

I cannot figure out what is going on and I cannot even post all of the html nor css here because some of it is reading from my wordpress blog theme, and the theme has about 20 different scripts linked.

I originally thought it had to do with how the full length is 12 columns, and the grey menu takes up 2 while the text takes up 9 - and that becoming an issue when the screen is resized to an odd number, but that doesn't make sense to me as much now.

Is this a common issue with responsive divs?

Comment: Your media queries are not very good.

Comment: So helpful, have a cookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table in `.span2` has a css `min-width: 170px` which is the cause of the `.span2` looks like overlapping with `.span9`. Fix that table width would help. For example give it a width 100%.

[edit]
Actually you could try  `.span3` and `.span8`?

Comment: This worked! Changed it to span 3 and 8 so that the page titles would fit into the table better.

Answer (score 0):

It can be tricky to keep your divs nicely responsive when you have measurements set in fixed amounts such as pixels. Instead, try using percentages. For fonts, ems are great, as you can reset the body size text in your media queries and scale everything accordingly.

For example, you might want to consider removing the min-width to eliminate the overlap issue.

Change this:

```
.whatwhat {
  min-width: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
  float: right;
 }
```

To this:

```
.whatwhat {
  overflow: auto;
  float: right;
}
```

On resize, the text will no longer flow outside of the div.

Answer (score 0):

I found overlap on window Width 768px - 979px, you can repair your media Queries
before,

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px)
.span9 {
width: 538px;
}
```

you can using this css below

```
   @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px)
    .span9 {
    width: 470px;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

This is happening because the width of `.span2` is bigger than what you are specifying in the stylesheet. For example at screen size `1199px` you have `.span2` width set to `width:140px;`, while the actual width is 196 pixels.